# What is the purpose of XDG_CONFIG_HOME in Flatpak applications config directory?

Tags: flatpak

I started developing an application to backup Flatpak applications.
According to [Flatpak documentation](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/conventions.html#xdg-base-directories), application configs are default located in `~/.var/app/<app-id>/config`.

What I don't understand though is that the base directories of this path is `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` which defaults to `$HOME/.config`.

If I understood correctly, the path for application config is constructed like this : `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/~/.var/app/<app-id>/config`. But then this is the same as only `~/.var/app/<app-id>/config`.

So, what are the differences between using `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/~/.var/app/<app-id>/config` or `~/.var/app/<app-id>/config` ?
And what I misunderstand ?